# How to prompt user for text input in a loop?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am writing an android app in that main activity starts and populates a list of contacts, and needs to prompt the user for today's rating of all the contacts(promptUserForInput) and immediately process received rating of all the contacts. I thought i can use a dialogue box that prompt for every contact and gets the rating from the user. But below code fails as the main thread is not waiting for the user to finish enter rating of all the users.

Here is my function which I am calling in the main activity in a do while loop for all the contact names. rating is a global variable.

```
double rating=0;
private synchronized void promptUserForInput(String firstName, String lastName) {

    final String fname = firstName;
    final String lName = lastName;

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    String custName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setTitle(custName);
    alert.setView(input);
    Log.v("Diva: in promptUserForInput", "setting positive buton");
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Editable res = input.getText();
            if(res == null) {
                Log.v("Diva..", "In positivebutton..befoer getting rating res is null");
            }
            rating = Double.valueOf(input.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            rating=0;
        }
    });

    alert.show();        

}
```

My caller of this `promptUserForInput()` looks like below.

```
// get list of contacts in a cursor
Cursor cursor = ManageDataBaseActivity.queryDataBase(this,     
ManageDataBaseActivity.CONTACT_INFO_TABLE);

if(cursor.getCount()>0) {

    double totalRatingForStats=0;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String[] colNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
        Log.v("Diva Colum names = ", colNames[0] + " " + colNames[1] + " " + colNames[2] + " " + colNames[3]);

        String firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));

        Log.v("Diva ..:", firstName);
        String lastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LastName"));
        String key = ManageDataBaseActivity.getDbKey(firstName, lastName, 
                                    date, ManageDataBaseActivity.CUSTOMER_DATA_TABLE);
        promptUserForInput(firstName, lastName);
        double ratingReceived = rating;

        totalRatingForStats = totalRatingForStats+ratingReceived;
        // some more processing

                        ManageDataBaseActivity.insertValueToDB(ManageDataBaseActivity.
                                CONTACT_DATA_TABLE+" ", .....);
    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: Don't.

The long answer: You should never block the main thread of a GUI program while waiting for user input.
Instead you should provide a continue button, which fires a event which causes the program to continue. There are several ways to accomplish this, the one that comes to mind first is signals and semaphores.

I'm not that well versed in Android programming - but there should be something similar in the API, perhaps dependent on Intents.

Answer (score 1):

Looping in the main thread of an Activity is generally not a very good idea. But you could implement something like a `pollNext()` method that gets the next dataset from the cursor and change your click-methods to this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // do your rating stuff

    // reads the next dataset
    pollNext();

    // shows the next dialog
    // of course, firstName and lastName must be membervariables to make this work
    promptUserForInput(firstName, lastName); 
}
```

The idea behind that is very common and also used in the [MVC-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)